# I need to add a consecutive index to a searchable string inside a file

Tags: bash, indexing

So I have a file called, say, 'test', with the contents:

39366

39371

45005

45005

216274

216277

216345

396480

396480

I need to add an index to the end of every string, which should correspond to the count of that string inside the file. It should look like this:

39366_1

39371_1

45005_1

45005_2

216274_1

216277_1

216345_1

396480_1

396480_2

396480_2

396480_3

Then I should repeat the process in another file, say 'test2' in a more complicated format, something like this:

+39366

ffasd

+39371

fasdasd

+45005

fasdfdf

+45005

asdfasdf

My first question here, I've never asked for anything, please help :)

Comment: What's your budget?

Answer (score -1):

$ cat script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1

n=$(cat $FILE | wc -l)

for (( i=1; i<=$n; i++ ))
do
    LINE=$(sed "${i}q;d" $FILE)

    if [ -n "$LINE" ]
    then
            INDEX=$(cat test | head -n $i | grep -c "$LINE")
            LINE="${LINE}_${INDEX}"
            sed -i "${i}s/.*/$LINE/" $FILE
    fi
done
```

$ cat test

```
39366

39371

45005

45005

216274

216277

216345

396480

396480

396480

396480
```

$ ./script.sh test

$ cat test

```
39366_1

39371_1

45005_1

45005_2

216274_1

216277_1

216345_1

396480_1

396480_2

396480_3

396480_4
```